# Free online tool for sending RSS to Kindle 3?

Tags: web-apps, rss, kindle

Is there some tool that can aggregate RSS feeds and send it once a day to Kindle?

I tried [Kindle4RSS](http://kindle4rss.com/), this works really cool, but automatic sending is only in paid version. I have circa 3 articles in month and paying 2$/month is quite expensive for it. I also don't need this cool article collection (all articles in one file), It could be simpler - articles one by one.

I also tried to find project on [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/), but without success.

Any ideas?

**Note**: I'm searhing for something online, not app.

Comment: Not sure about the automatism part, but have you checked with [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)? Next to ebook conversions, this also collects RSS feeds as you described.